# reshape package: data.frame from wide to long

Tags: r

Using the following data,

```
 library(reshape)
 P     <- c( "D" , "D" , "P" )
 a_0_2 <- c( "M" , "Y" , "M" )
 a_3_5 <- c( "M" , "M" , "Y" )
 n     <- c( 48  , 57  , 15  )
 df <- data.frame( P , a_0_2 , a_3_5 , n )
```

I'd like to get to the following data.frame:

```
 P variable value nIDs
 D    a_0_2     M   48
 D    a_0_2     Y   57
 P    a_0_2     M   15
 D    a_3_5     M   48
 D    a_3_5     M   57
 P    a_3_5     Y   15
```

I tried `melt( df , id.vars = "P" )` which of course doesn't treat the `n` variable correctly:

```
   P variable value
 1 D    a_0_2     M
 2 D    a_0_2     Y
 3 P    a_0_2     M
 4 D    a_3_5     M
 5 D    a_3_5     M
 6 P    a_3_5     Y
 7 D        n  <NA>
 8 D        n  <NA>
 9 P        n  <NA>
 Warning message:
 In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(48, 57, 15)) :
   invalid factor level, NA generated
```

However using the intuitive `melt( df , id.vars = "P" , measure.vars = "n" )` call produces

```
   P variable value
 1 D        n    48
 2 D        n    57
 3 P        n    15
```

which is further away from the objective. What is it that am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Why are both D/a_3_5/M rows 48? - shouldn't one be 57?

Comment: A lot of people prefer `reshape2` to `reshape`.

Comment: @thelatemail, yes, typo on my part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you simply need this

```
melt(df, id.vars = c("P", "n"))
#   P  n variable value
# 1 D 48    a_0_2     M
# 2 D 57    a_0_2     Y
# 3 P 15    a_0_2     M
# 4 D 48    a_3_5     M
# 5 D 57    a_3_5     M
# 6 P 15    a_3_5     Y
```

---

Or using the newer `tidyr` packge

```
library(tidyr)
gather(df, variable, value, a_0_2:a_3_5)
#   P  n variable value
# 1 D 48    a_0_2     M
# 2 D 57    a_0_2     Y
# 3 P 15    a_0_2     M
# 4 D 48    a_3_5     M
# 5 D 57    a_3_5     M
# 6 P 15    a_3_5     Y
```

---

If we assume that `df[2:3]` aren't necessarily factors (adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to OPs `data.frame` function), we can add a nice solution proposed by @Thela using base R only

```
data.frame(df[c(1, 4)], stack(df[2:3]))
#   P  n values   ind
# 1 D 48      M a_0_2
# 2 D 57      Y a_0_2
# 3 P 15      M a_0_2
# 4 D 48      M a_3_5
# 5 D 57      M a_3_5
# 6 P 15      Y a_3_5
```

Comment: `data.frame(df[c("P","n")],stack(lapply(df[2:3],as.character)))` for a base solution. Complicated somewhat by `stack` not accepting `factor` variables directly.

Comment: Thanks David & thelatemail.

Comment: @thelatemail, nice one. I wouldn't necessarily assume OP has factors there and maybe they just created their example incorrectly, I would add that as additional option with your permission

Comment: @DavidArenburg - go for it, I won't sick my lawyers on you. :-)